# Node js server not showing changes to files even after restart

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, hadoop-yarn

I'm working on a node js server that runs on a raspberry pi.
I implemented some changes recently, they worked as expected when I ran them on the dev PC using

```
yarn start
```

But when I copied the changed over to the pi they wouldn't appear and the site stayed the same.

I have tried restarting the server. I have tried rebooting the pi (server is set to launch when the pi starts). I have tried clearing both the browser I use and npm cache.

Comment: Did you save the files?

Comment: The chances are the app you see in browser is not the one you started. I would first stop it, verify in browser it does not run and then start it ideally with `node <main-script-name-here>.js`. Make sure there is no EADDRINUSE error which would indicate that another app is running, probably from different directory.

Comment: @code 
Turns out I was just being dumb and not running `yarn build` before transferring the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you develop with typescript?
if yes, are you build your project before restart?

Comment: Yes. Building it solved the problem.